# Conditional Probability of a Product of Probabilities

Tags: conditional-probability, independence, products

What is the conditional probability of a product of probabilities? More precisely, suppose that $P(C) = P(A)P(B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are any two events which are not necessarily mutually independent. Consider another event $X$ (not necessarily independent of $A$ and/or $B$).

What is $P(C|X)$?

Would it be incorrect to say that it is simply: $P(C|X)=P(A|X)P(B|X)$?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: $P(A)$ has no meaning for a random variable $A$.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose $A,B,C,X$ are all events and not random variables. Consider $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure and take $A=(0,1), B=(0,\frac  1 2), C=(\frac 1 2,1)$ and $X=C$ to get a counter-example.

Comment: I meant "event," not RV, sorry.

Comment: Indeed, that is a counter-example to P(C|X) = P(A|X)P(B|X), thank you! Any thoughts on how to find P(C|X) in general for arbitrary A,B,X?

Comment: In general you can only apply the definition : $P(C|X)=\frac {P(C \cap X)} {P(X)}$. Nothing  more can be said using yuor hypotheis. @MAC

Answer (score 0):

To bring some meaning to the calculations, let's roll a (fair, six-sided) die and say:

- $A$ is the event that it's a $5$
- $B$ is the event that it's even
- $C$ is the event that it's a multiple of 3

Then $P(A)=\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{3}=P(B)P(C)$.

If $X=A$ (i.e. we roll the die and it's a $5$) then $P(A|X)=1\neq 0\times 0=P(B|X)P(C|X)$.

When we put it this way, it seems rather odd that we would expect the statement to be true: that two probabilities multiply together to give a different probability says nothing about the relation between the events.

However, when looking just at the formulae, we are used to seeing $P(A)=P(B)P(C)$ in the context that $A$ is the combination of two independent events $B$ and $C$ both happening, when the formula $P(A|X)=P(B|X)P(C|X)$ does hold). If we changed $A$ to be the event that the die lands on $6$ then we can see that this would work for our example above.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. Assuming that A and B are independent, then: P(C) = P(A)P(B) = P(A&B), so that P(C|X) = P(A&B|X) = P(A|B&X)P(B|X) = P(A|X)P(B|X). But this is not true in the general case where A and B are not necessarily independent.

Comment: @MAC My naming was different to yours, but my example *still* provides a counterexample to what you claim here as my events $B$ and $C$ *are* independent from each other. The condition is stricter than the events being independent: the event $A$ (in my naming) would have to be the event "both $B$ and $C$ happen (and $B,C$ are independent)", which is *not* the same as $P(A)=P(B\cap C)$ (which does not indicate any meaningful relation between $A,B,C$). Re-read my answer with this in mind.

Comment: The mistake in your chain of equalities is $P(C|X)=P(A&B|X)$ - this only works if the event $C$ is the same event as $A&B$ but the fact that they have the same probabilities does not mean they are the same event ("the die lands on $n$" will have the same probability for any $n$, but that doesn't mean you can change the value of $n$ retroactively after rolling the die).

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I would recommend using the originator's notation (that would be mine) to avoid confusion. Indeed you have provided a counterexample to P(C|X)=P(A|X)P(B|X), which is not true *in general.* However, if A and B are independent, then *by definition* P(AB)=P(A)P(B), so conditionalizing both sides wrt X gives P(AB|X)=P(A|X)P(B|X), as shown. I.e., conditionalizing a product [P(A)P(B)] wrt X is the same as the product of the individual conditionalizations, *provided* that A&B are independent, but not necessarily otherwise.

Comment: Notice also that "Die lands 5" and "Die lands even" are not independent events, so they do not invalidate the case when A&B are independent, namely when P(AB)=P(A)P(B) (by definition). In that case (and that case only), namely when P(C)=P(A)P(B) and A&B are independent, P(C|X)=P(A|X)P(B|X) holds.

Comment: @MAC you are still misreading the comment. "Your" A,B correspond to "my" B,C, and the events "die is even" and "die is a multiple of 3" are independent. Even if $P(C)=P(A&B)$, that does not mean $P(C|X)=P(A&B|X)$, as in the example I have already given. In your notation, A is "die is even", B is "die is a multiple of 3" and C is "die is 5". X is "die is 6". A and B are independent. $P(C)=P(A&B)=1/6$ but $P(C|X)=0$ and $P(A&B|X)=1$.

Comment: Your counterexample is correct and it proves your point perfectly. I wasn't paying close enough attention to your different notation. Thanks again.